# Comparing dates in Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to compare two sequelize dates with formats:
'3/25/19 8:21:22 PM +00:00'

I'm not sure why Sequelize makes this so complicated. Here's what I've tried based on other responses on SO. None of which worked:

```
where: { createdAt: { $gt: sequelize.col('createdAt') }}
where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('convert', 'datetime', sequelize.col('createdAt')), '<=', sequelize.fn('convert', 'datetime', createdAt))
sequelize.where( sequelize.fn('date', sequelize.col('createdAt')), '<=',sequelize.fn('date', createdAt),)
```

I'm using microsoft SQL. Any ideas?

Comment: Clarification: createdAt is a variable with a sequelize date

Answer (score 0):

Your example is comparing a field to itself, so I am guessing you got no results.

```
where: { createdAt: { $gt: sequelize.col('createdAt') }}
```

The syntax should work if you change the 2nd field...

```
where: { createdAt: { $gt: sequelize.col('someOtherDateField') }}
```

Comment: I'm sorry my bad. I should've clarified. The 'createdAt' is a variable passed in.

Comment: Convert the date string to a date variable: `var dateParam = new Date('3/20/19 0:21:22 PM +00:00');` (and maybe throw an error if it's not formatted corectly) then modify the findAll to use the date variable 
        `where: { createdAt:  {$gt : dateParam}}`